# How to inject an service into controller by angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angular.js from the website below, http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.injecting_controllers

I tried to run the snippet in my local server. But it failed.
I thought the issue was that the controller did not know the 'notify' factory.
Could someone help to correct the codes?Thanks.

**html**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div id="simple" ng-controller="myController">
    <p>Let's try this simple notify service, injected into the controller...</p>
    <input ng-init="message='test'" ng-model="message" >
    <button ng-click="callNotify(message);">NOTIFY</button>
    <p>(you have to click 3 times to see an alert)</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 <script>
//MyServiceModule service module
angular.module('MyServiceModule', []).factory('notify', ['$window', function(win) {
    var msgs = [];
    return function(msg) {
    msgs.push(msg);
    if (msgs.length == 3) {
    win.alert(msgs.join("\n"));
    msgs = [];
    }
    };
}]);
//Controller
function myController(scope, notifyService) {
    scope.callNotify = function(msg) {
    notifyService(msg);
    };
}
myController.$inject = ['$scope','notify'];
// How to let the myController know the 'notify' factory in MyServiceModule?

//myApp
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController',myController);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app must declare dependcie for the other module like this:

```
//myApp
angular.module('myApp', ["MyServiceModule"])
.controller('myController',myController);
```